# Doubt on $f: \mathbb{R} \to (0,1) \cup (2,3) $ homeomorphism.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

A particular annoying question is bothering me. The question is:

> Do exist some homeomorphism $f: \mathbb{R} \to (0,1) \cup (2,3) $?

I really need some help. I've already discussed with my professor but all that he says is "use the definition". I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: Have you studied connectedness?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy just in a wave handing way. I didn't get the point of the question though.

Comment: Continuous image of a connected space is connected.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy so?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is connected and $(0,1) \cup (2,3)$ is not connected. Now read the comment of @KaviRamaMurthy one more time

Comment: @KaiL1ng so since the union set isn't connected, cannot exist a $f^{-1}$? Also, since the image of a continuous function $f$ "must to be connected" we arrive at a absurd?

Comment: I mean: is there a homeomorphism $f: \mathbb{R} \to (0,1) \cup (2,3)$?

Well,

Suppose that $f$ is a homeomorphism, then the continuous image $(0,1) \cup (2,3)$ is a connected space, which is a absurd. Hence do not exist my estimated homeomorphism.

Comment: Yes, if $f$ is a homeomorphism, then $f$ is a continuous continuous bijection. Additionally, $g=f^{-1}$ a continuous bijection. Since $g$ is continuous, $g(\mathbb{R})$ must be connected, which is not satisfied, since the function is bijective and therefore surfective.

Comment: @KaiL1ng could you please write a answer with details? I mean, if you could.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: If $f$ is a homeomorphism, then $f$ is a bijection and it is continuous. What does each of these two properties in turn mean for $f^{-1}((0,1))$ and $f^{-1}((2,3))$?

Comment: that they are continuous?

Comment: Intervals aren't continuous. Functions are continuous. What's the definition of continuous? What does that mean for the two sets I wrote above?

Comment: that $f^{-1}$ maps the interval $(0,1)$, say, into $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: That's part of the definition of function. What's the definition of _continuous_ function?

Comment: All right, let me try something here:

You said $f^{-1}((0,1))$ and $f^{-1}((2,3))$ for a reason. I think that they are continuous. Hence $f^{-1}((0,1) \cup (2,3))$ will be and therefore exist the homeomorphism.

Comment: I also said "What is the definition of a continuous function?" for a reason. Do you know what that definition is?

Comment: A function from one metric space to another, $f:A \to B$, is continuous at $p$ if for all $ϵ>0$ there exists $δ>0$ such that
$d(x,p)<δ \implies d(f(x),f(p))<ϵ$.

Comment: That's one definition, from analysis and calculus. Do you know the definition from general topology? It is **much** easier to work with in this problem.

Comment: No I don't. That's the definition given to me in lectures.

Comment: still don't get the point if exist a homeomorphism

Comment: The issue here is, if that's the only definition of continuity you have to work with, I am afraid that this might go from an elegant three-line proof to a page of calculations. Someone might still have some bright idea, but a topological problem really, really fits the topological definition of continuity a lot better. I would never in a million years give this problem to someone who didn't know that definition.

Comment: @Arthur could you please write a answer with details? I mean, if you could.

Comment: @BasicMathGuy It doesn't exist. If you need the proof by only using the definition, you could ask a new question, and indicate this, add also the tag ´epsilon-delta´ and include your attempts. And don't include the tag `topology`

Answer (score 2):

Assume $f: \mathbb{R} \to (0,1) \cup (2,3)$ is a homeomorphism. Therefore, $f$ must be a continuous bijection.

We know that $\mathbb{R}$ is connected and $(0,1) \cup (2,3)$ is not connected. The image of a connected space is again connected. Since $f$ is bijective and therefore surjective, we see that $f(\mathbb{R}) = (0,1) \cup (2,3)$. We have a contradiction and it follows that $f$ cannot be continuous, so $f$ cannot be a homeomorphism.

Comment: +1 By contradiction, and short+clear.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is defined on the interval $\mathbb{R}$ and it is continuous there.  Also $f$ is on the set $(0,1)\cup (2,3)$, which means that there are $a,b$ such that $f(a)=1/2$ and $f(b)=5/2$. So $f$ is continous on the interval [a,b] and from calculus it should take all the   numbers between [1/2, 5/2]...but this is  impossible bcs $1$ does not belong to it's range. This proves the statement.

Homomorfism is too strong here... Just continuity and onto is enough.